# javascript onclick combining 2 events does not work on ios (iPhone, iPad)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, iframe, onclick

I'm combining 2 javascripts in the `onclick` to do 2 things:
1. Stop an audio player
2. Load and iframe that has a video

The following code works on all browsers but not iOS (iPhone, iPad)

```
<a class="aboutclick" href="#" onclick="stop2();document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML='&lt;iframe src=&quot;paul-on-paul.html&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;600&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;no&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;'"><img src="assets/video-cold.jpg" alt="paul-gregory-video" width="161" height="81" border="0" /></a>
```

The `stop2()` in the beginning of the `onclick` code is what turns off the music player.  (it's Flash audio player so it doesn't apply to iOS). Tapping on the image does nothing on the iPad, iPhone with this code present.

If I remove `stop2();` from the `onclick` code the iframe will load on iOS devices.

I need to be able to use the `stop2()` to kill the music but I also need it to work on the iOS devices.

Any suggestions?

Working example: http://www.fixxed.com/test/pg  (click on the video thumbnail at lower right)

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you move your move all your onclick code into a function and then call that function on click, like this:

```
window.foo = function(e) {
    stop2();
    document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML='<iframe src="paul-on-paul.html" width="100%" height="600%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>'
}

...

<a class="aboutclick" href="#" onclick="foo">
  <img src="assets/video-cold.jpg" alt="paul-gregory-video" width="161" height="81" border="0" />
</a>
```

That just makes things much nicer to read and more maintainable. Then I would suggest that you look into using mobile touch events instead of click events, you will end up with something like this:

```
window.foo = function(e) {
    stop2();
}

window.bar = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML='<iframe src="paul-on-paul.html" width="100%" height="600%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>';
}

...

<a class="aboutclick" href="#" onclick="foo" ontouchstart='bar'>
  <img src="assets/video-cold.jpg" alt="paul-gregory-video" width="161" height="81" border="0" />
</a>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this code with no avail, but just adding the stop2() at the END of my code works great.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like iOS is choking on your `stop2()` call. You might want to try detecting if the browser is an iOS device (one simple and not-so-good way of doing that might be with the user-agent string) or (better) check to see if the browser supports that functionality using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). Then, if you detect that it's an iOS browser, just return from `stop2()`.

Comment: this is a very bad answer and not helpful in any way. he should use addEventListener to attach a central function to his onclick event. Further, he should feature detect something in his stop2 function, that he just assumes is arround, which iOS seems to chocke on. "just return from stop2" is not a solution, if he has other things he needs to happen

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to disagree with your comment on a couple of points. He mentioned that stop2() is a function to turn off Flash music, which he mentions does nothing for iOS devices. Therefore, if he just returned from it after detecting an iOS device, he'd be fine. I agree that he should use a centralized function for the onclick event, but the answer above already mentions that; plus, that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: I just ended up adding the `stop2()` at the end of the code and it works.